# Pagination is missing in mobile search

Tags: discussion, status-completed, search, mobile-web

I always find it irritating when developers do not implement basic features to a mobile version of a site. Is there a particular reason for this issue?

Comment: The mobile site has always been a second-class citizen, unfortunately.

Comment: We're discussing this during today's Core team meeting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be out in the next deployment.

Curiously, the fix was literally 1 char, `@`. I'll let the Razor experts fill in the gaps.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, was it @media screen?

Comment: @the4kman nope, but good attempt

Comment: *curiosity of course. A spelling corrector function would help me here on SO a lot.